# How to use a method on page load? VueX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm learning Vue with Vuex, I made a method called 'llamarJson'this method get a json data.
I don't know how to use it when the page load. I tried many ways but I could not find a solution.
I'm using Vue and Vuex.
Please, could you help me?

That's the code html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vue</title>
    <!-- Vue -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <!-- Vuex -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.6.0/dist/vuex.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="caja-vue">
        <actividades></actividades>
    </div>
    


    <script src="codigo.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

That's the JS code:

```
    //componentes
Vue.component('actividades', {
    template: /*html*/
        `  <div>
            <h1>Hello friend</h1>
                <ul v-for="item of actividades">
                    <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        `,
    computed: {
        ...Vuex.mapState(['actividades'])
    },
    methods: {
        ...Vuex.mapActions(['llamarJson'])
    }
});

//VueEx
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        actividades: [],
        programas: []
    },
    mutations: {
        llamarJsonMutation(state, llamarJsonAction){
            state.actividades = llamarJsonAction;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        llamarJson: async function(){
            const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
            const actividades = await data.json();
            commit('llamarJsonMutation', actividades);
        }
    }
});

//Vue
new Vue({
    el: '#caja-vue',
    store: store
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use vue life cycle hooks for this, read the link below:

[Vue life cycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)

these are vue hooks:

**Creation Hooks**

beforeCreate(): events and lifecycle have been initialized but data has not been made reactive

created(): you have access to data and events that are reactive but templates and virtual DOM have not yet been mounted or rendered

**Mounting Hooks**

beforeMount(): runs before the initial render

mounted(): you have access to the reactive component, templates and rendered DOM

**Updating Hooks**

beforeUpdate(): runs after data changes and before the DOM is re-rendered

updated(): runs after data changes and the DOM is re-rendered

**Destruction Hooks**

beforeDestroy(): runs before tear down

destroyed(): runs after tear down

for page load depending on your need (if you want to have access to DOM or not) you may use `created()` or `mounted()` hooks.

just define them in your vue component object and call your method in them like this:

```
created() {
  this.someMethod();
}
```

in your case you can also call the vuex action from the created (or any other hook) directly like this:

```
created() {
  this.$store.dispatch('vuexAction');
}
```

Comment: in this case inside the created lifecycle method you'd call your function `this.llamarJson();`